# Silverlight ListboxDragDropTarget: Horizontal Scroll bar not behaving properly

Tags: silverlight-5.0

In my silverlight 5 application, I am using a listbox inside a ListboxDragDropTarget control. My listbox contains more than 100 items. Whenever I attempt to drag an item to the left, when the horizontal scroll bar is scrolled to the right, it immediately reset the scroll all the way to the left It also doesn't automatically move the scrollbar as the I move the item to the right or left. Any solution?
Thanks in Advance